# Access a variable within 2 modules elixir

Tags: elixir

I am using a method to connect with a `server` as

```
  connect_to_server(ip, username, password)
  |> check_status_for_server()

  defp check_status_for_server({:error, :nxdomain}), do: {"IP doesn't seem correct.", :error}
  defp check_status_for_server({:error, :timeout}), do: {"Server is giving timeout.", :error}
  defp check_status_for_server({:error, reason}), do: {reason, :error}
  defp check_status_for_server({:ok, connection}), do: {true, connection}

  defp connect_to_server(ip, username, password), do:
    SSHEx.connect(ip: ip, user: username, password: password)
```

as a result of the successful connection, I am getting `connection`, all the above things work when a user clicks a button in the form, and form contains 2 buttons, 1 is making this connection and 2nd is supposed to use that connection (both are ajax requests.)

But as you can see both buttons are sending an ajax request and both ajax calls hitting 2 `def`s, One is making connection and 2nd one is doing operation while using that connection, I have no idea how to make this connection created once and available in 2nd def as well.

this is end method for 2nd ajax call 
`def create_raid(conn, params) do` and this is first one

```
  def details_about_raid(conn, %{"ip" => ip, "username" => username, "password" => password} = _params) do
    connect_to_server(ip, username, password)
    |> check_status_for_server()
    |> still_in_pipe_operate(conn)
  end
```

I tried to send connection pid back to ajax response but it failed. any help would be thankful.

Update:
I tried to save the connection pids in ets table with a key and got this error.

```
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (ArgumentError) argument error
        (stdlib) :ets.insert(:connection, {"70122EE1441B746788CD11FC83B3B211", #PID<0.435.0>})
```

I have my connections table created within the Repo module already.

UPDATE:

I was initializing the ETS table wrongly,

```
  def start_ets_connection do
    :ets.new(:connection, [:set, :protected, :named_table])
  end
```

It should be `:public` instead of `:protected`, Now its working fine and I can save conn to ETS as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the connection somewhere on the server. I'd suggest the following:

In the first AJAX request:

1. Connect to the remote server (like you're doing already).
2. Create a random key. (You can use e.g. `:crypto.strong_rand_bytes(16) |> Base.encode16()`)
3. Store the key along with the connection in an ETS table or an Agent.
4. Return the random key to the client.

In the second AJAX request:

1. Send the key that the first request returned to the server.
2. Get the connection out of the ETS table or Agent with the key.
3. Use this connection.

Comment: on saving in Agent, How I will get that PID? after 2nd AJAX request?

Comment: If you're storing a map in the agent, you'll set it using `Agent.update(..., &Map.put(&1, key, conn))` and get it using `Agent.get(..., &Map.get(&1, key))`.